How to filter in pandas by more complicated conditions that rely on more than specific columns
How does one filter a dataframe efficiently when the conditional is more complicated than
df_filtered = df[df["A"] > 0 & df["B"] < 5]

For example I want all rows in a dataframe that have Euclidian distance of a vector made from the row to a given vector and filter by a specific radius.
I'd prefer a generic solution to complicated conditional filter for future use.
for example passing a function that filters all elements that return False when the function is applied to them (if it is fast enough)
I've tried iterating the dataframe and appending to a list only those that satisfied the condition
list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if(euclidean(row.values, vector) <= maximum):
       list.append(row)

but this solution is simply way too slow.
In the end, the idea is to find nearest vectors to a given vector for classifications just like in RadiusNearestNeighbors.

IIUC, you can just filter using np.linalg.norm:
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [4, 3, 2, 1], "C": [1, 3, 2, 4]})

vector = np.array([1, 2, 3])
maximum = 3

df = df[np.linalg.norm(df.values - vector, axis=1) <= maximum]

For this example dataframe, result would be:
   A  B  C
0  1  4  1
1  2  3  3
2  3  2  2


If you already have a euclidean function, just try using np.apply_along_axis:
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [4, 3, 2, 1], "C": [1, 3, 2, 4]})

vector = np.array([1, 2, 3])
maximum = 3

df[np.apply_along_axis(euclidean, 1, df.values - vector) <= maximum]

Output:
   A  B  C
0  1  4  1
1  2  3  3
2  3  2  2

If you don't want to use your euclidean function, just replace it with np.linalg.norm.
